# Unclear syntax with function parameters in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am reading open layers documentation which can be found at [this link](http://openlayersbook.github.io/ch11-creating-web-map-apps/example-02.html), but I do not understand something about syntax.

There is a part of the code which goes like this:

```
function flickrStyle(feature) {
      //where does this feature come from?
      var style = new ol.style.Style({
        image: new ol.style.Circle({
          radius: 6,
          stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: 'white',
            width: 2
          }),
          fill: new ol.style.Fill({
            color: 'green'
          })
        })
      });
      return [style];
    }

    var flickrLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
      style: flickrStyle //??? where is parameter which needs to be sent? Should this be something like flickrStyle(someParam)
    });
```

As you can see, source is extracted from flickrStyle function, which obviously requires feature parameter, but I can't see anywhere in code that parameter is actually sent.

How does this work?

Comment: Probably from css or javasvript funtion that loaded from <link rel=style> or script tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit clearer if you format it reasonably and consistently (as is often the case):

```
function flickrStyle(feature) {
    //where does this feature come from?
    var style = new ol.style.Style({
        image: new ol.style.Circle({
            radius: 6,
            stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                color: 'white',
                width: 2
            }),
            fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                color: 'green'
            })
        })
    });
    return [style];
}

var flickrLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    style: flickrStyle //??? where is parameter which needs to be sent? Should this be something like flickrStyle(someParam)
});
```

The `style: flickrStyle` property in the object being passed to `ol.layer.Vector` is passing the **function** reference itself, not a call to it. Looking at the [`ol.layer.Vector` documentation](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.layer.Vector.html), `ol.layer.Vector` knows to *call* the function (passing in an argument for the `feature` parameter) if/when necessary.

Apparently that particular function doesn't use the `feature` parameter (and could have just omitted it from the parameter list), but perhaps the author left it there because it does get passed a value for that parameter (per the [`StyleFunction` docs](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.html#.StyleFunction) linked from the docs above) and the function may be edited to use it later.

Here's a simpler example of the same sort of thing:

```js
// Stand-in for ol.layer.Vector
class Foo {
  constructor(options) {
    this.style = options.style;
    this.counter = 0;
  }
  addElement() {
    const div = document.createElement("div");
    ++this.counter;
    div.innerHTML = "Div #" + this.counter;
    if (typeof this.style === "function") {
      this.style(div); // <=== This is like ol.layer.Vector's call to the function
    }
    document.body.appendChild(div);
  }
}

// Our style function
function ourStyleFunction(element) {
  element.style.color = Math.random() < 0.5 ? "blue" : "green";
  element.style.fontWeight = "bold";
}

// Creating an object passing in that function as an option
const f = new Foo({
  style: ourStyleFunction
});

// Doing something with it that makes it call the function
f.addElement();
f.addElement();
f.addElement();
f.addElement();
```

Comment: I get it now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You're right, `feature` isn't used in that method.

```
var flickrLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    style: flickrStyle // this is a function reference, so the Vector class will call it with a given parameter (probably "feature")
});
```